# Prove that if a curves normal lines all pass through a single point, then the curve must be a circle

Tags: differential-geometry

We can assume that the curve is parameterized by a unit speed curve, r.

I know that if all of its normals are going through a point then there is some smooth function l(s) and a fixed point p such that p=r(s)+l(s)N(s) for all s.

How can I show that l is constant?

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both sides we get $0=\dot{r}+\dot{l}N(s) + l(s)\dot{N}(s)$.
Since $|N(s)|=1$, we have $\langle \dot{N}, N \rangle=0$. Inner product with $N$ for both sides of the first equation we get $0=\langle \dot{r}, N\rangle + \dot{l} + 0$. That is $0=\dot{l}$ since $\langle \dot{r}, N\rangle=0$ by definition.

Comment: Btw, thank you so much for the help!